# How to read an empty table/csv as NA instead of getting an error?

Tags: r, csv, web-scraping

I use a `read.csv()` function in a Markdown document when webscraping a public database for information each day. Sometimes the data isn't reported, and when the function tries to read the csv generated from the link an error is thrown:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  first five rows are empty: giving up
```

I am wondering if there is a way to specify that a blank table/row should be replaced with a single NA value instead of the error being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I disagree that a row with `NA`s is necessarily the right way to go. To me, there is a distinct difference between "no data" (0 rows) and "data of nulls" as you requested.

Having said that, then you can do something like this to force it after the file has been read in:

```r
dat <- read.csv(text='a,b')
dat
# [1] a b
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
dat[seq_len(max(1, nrow(dat))),]
#     a  b
# NA NA NA
```

This does nothing when there is actual data:

```r
dat <- read.csv(text='a,b\n1,1\n2,2')
dat[seq_len(max(1, nrow(dat))),]
#   a b
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 2
```